# fopen creating the new file is always upper case

Tags: c, file

I am writing a small program which needs to create a new file with the user's content in "C" program using following code.

```
FILE *fp = fopen ("test.txt", "wb");

fclose (fp);
```

The result is creating a new file with same name but in upper case like "TEST.TXT".

How Can I fix this.

Note:
I am using Turbo C, in windows with .c extension.

Comment: I just tried on my machine and I don't encounter the same issue.

Comment: Anywho, Turbo C is an obsolete compiler. I'd say it's even worse than MS VC++ 6.0. Why not use mingw-gcc or VS 7?

Comment: thanks @moshbear, I know Turbo C is obselete, but unable to figure out why this issue comes which I am going to integrate the code in embedded web server once the testing is over in turbo C.

Comment: Why are using Turbo C though?

Comment: My guess is the following: Turbo C was designed for DOS, so it does case folding of file names. Test the following: `fopen("abcdefg0123.txt", "wb")` and `fopen("abcdefg2456.txt", "wb")`. If it creates files `ABCDEF~1.TXT` and `ABCDEF~2.TXT`, then Turbo C is at fault.

Comment: Could be an OS thing, that format looks like Microsoft 8.3 file-name format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Turbo C it's probably happening because it's using old MS-DOS APIs to access the file system. Those APIs likely force filenames to uppercase for compatibility purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead and implement on live webserver